# How to test async Mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, scala, unit-testing, asynchronous, integration-testing

Is there any good strategy to test an async `insert` to a mongodb collection using MongoDB Scala driver 1.1:

```
driver.myCollection.insertOne(doc).subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {

      override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = /* do something */

      override def onComplete(): Unit = /* do something */

      override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = /* do something */
    })
```

Any mock suggested to run in it in a test? Mocking the Observable? And in case of integration test?

Comment: You can subscribe to the different methods and then turn the observable into a `Future` and `Await.result` on it.

Comment: how do you turn the observable into a future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to invoke `insertOne` and turn the `Observable[T]` into a `Future[T]` and use `Await.result` to synchronously block on it. This conversion is defined inside the [ScalaObservable[T]](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/scaladoc/index.html#org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ScalaObservable@toFuture():scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[T]]) implicit class:

```
import org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits._

val future = driver
              .myCollection
              .insertOne(docs)
              .toFuture()

Await.result(future, Duration(3000, MILLISECONDS))
```

Note this requires the import of `ObservableImplicits`.

Comment: I cannot do it. I think you have to replace the `subscribe` with the `toFuture`. The future will work as observable itself.